# How to sort column names of dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting

I need to  use R to print dataset of a dataframe so that columns are in alphabetical order. It sounds sorting column name is required. I tried sort (data.frame$) but it didn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Add at least a tag about python and pandas so people will find your question

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is about R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below

```
df[order(names(df))]
```

or

```
df[sort(names(df))]
```